# File.ReadAllText does not return full content in C#

Tags: c#

In my c# program, I have an image which is successfully stored in a `byte[]` data called bytes. I successfully write it into a .txt file using the following code

```
using (FileStream file = new FileStream("text.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    file.Write(bytes, 0, numToWrite);
    file.Close();
}
```

The above code stores the exact content I wish to store.

Whenever I wish to read the content of the file, text.txt, into textbox I only get the first line or little part of the first line. But when I open the file, text.txt, I see the complete content.

This is the code I use to read the file

```
string kk = File.ReadAllText("text.txt");
```

Comment: What is the value of `numToWrite` ? In the first code the file extension is text instead of txt. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: according to the file I'm converting to byte 
numToWrite = 101410;

Comment: The file extension is .txt

Comment: Binary data is not text. To fix your issue, you'll have to learn to acknowledge the differences.

Comment: The mere fact that a file has a `.txt` extension **does not** make it a *text* file per se. You write *binary* data into a file, and then try reading it as if it were a *text* which is subject to some encoding like UTF-8. That won't work. Ever.

Comment: Try using `file.flush` before closing file stream.

Comment: OK I have the text file containing the data either in text or binary. All I see is a content that is unreadable. But I am still able to compile the content in the text.txt back to its original data. 

All I need is get the whole content into a textbox object in the program.
Please help me out.

Comment: Binary data is not text. Displaying binary data as if it were will not ever work. You will have to transform it first into a human-readable format. You need to take a step back and understand the differences between text and binary data.

Comment: Try to figure why folks down voted this question?  Its a valid question and the OP presented his code and put forth effort.  Please explain why this question would be downvoted.

Comment: "All I need is get the whole content into a textbox object in the program" - you've started with an *image* which is binary data. A textbox is for *text*. Now you *can* convert arbitrary binary data into text without losing information (e.g. using hex or base64) but I suspect you haven't done that. Would you really want 101K of text in a textbox anyway? I suggest taking a step back and working out whether this approach is really the best one to achieve your overall goal (which we don't know about).

Comment: @JeffOrris: Lack of research would be a good reason to downvote. If you read the documentation for `ReadAllText`, it's telling you right there, how that call is trying to interpret the data. Another reason would be, that the question doesn't make sense, as explained by Daisy Shipton above. And I'm fairly convinced, that this question or any moral equivalent to treating binary data like text has been asked and answered before. There is really no reason at all to upvote this.

Comment: A big that you to @Daisy Shipton, who opened my eyes to areas I quickly overlooked. 
Moreover, I also thank the entire contributors to this topic. 


I was really working on an Advanced Steganography and the problem has been solved using your idea. Thanks so much all of you.

Comment: Hello guys. It seems I'm unable to post questions again on stackoverflow because of the -2 down vote on this question. Your help is required distinguished fellows. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have said at the start of the question that you have a `byte[]` that you are writing into the file. It's not clear why you decided not to use [File.WriteAllBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) but let's assume that your code is correctly writing all the data into the file called "text.txt", which has been explained in comments does not magically make this a text file.

Using [File.ReadAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx) is not going to work because The data in the file is binary data, not text. As you can see from the remarks on the documentation, it will try to decide the encoding of the text file (which won't work because it contains binary data) and will do end of line processing which you won't want for a binary file.

The best way to read the data back is to use [File.ReadAllBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx), which gives you back a `byte[]`, just like you started with.

Comment: Your idea was really superb and it also helped me a lot. I thank you @Richardisssimo

Comment: Moreover, I see no reason why viewers should down vote this topic. It's really confusing.

Comment: Down voting happens for a lot of reasons. In my experience tends to be more about the specific question than the topic.

Comment: You had originally tagged this question as [tag:windows] but if you look at the description of that tag it says *"Use this tag only if your question relates to using Windows APIs or Windows-specific behavior related to your code, not just because you happen to run your code on Windows"*. So my guess would be that people who are good at that topic, and monitor questions with that tag were annoyed by it and down voted.

Comment: Thumbs up brother. 